# Is it possible to use Image Capture to scan over WiFi with an EPSON SX620FW, and how to set that up?

Tags: scanning

I'm wondering whether it's possible to use Image Capture to scan over WiFi with my EPSON All-in-One SX620FW? If so, how can I set it up?

I've found [instructions from someone claiming it works with their EPSON PX710W](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10568641#10568641), but I haven't been able to replicate these. I can scan without problems over WiFi using the bundled EPSON Scan application, but am wondering if and how I could use Image Capture instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software Update provided me with an update for EPSON printers today and now I can use my EPSON SX620FW to scan over WiFi with Image Capture, no additional setup needed (apart from adding the device in the Print&Fax system preferences panel)!

The update is also available through Apple's website:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL900

Answer (score 1):

I've got an NX420, and I can use the scanner with Image Capture over WiFi. What did it for me was *installing the drivers that came on the CD* (the ones Apple included didn't do it, and neither did the ones on the Epson website).

You might try that.